# PHP - Create folder on remote server and upload file

Tags: php, remote-access

I have pem key to access remote servers (there are 4 servers on one load balancer). How can I make new folder on each of them, and then upload the file on every server? Is this possible to do with php?

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the servers?  `ssh`?  You can use the [SSH functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) if you install the [ssh2 PECL library](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2).  Then have a look at `ssh2_sftp_mkdir()` and `ssh2_scp_send()`.

Comment: I have only ssh access.

Comment: If you can install the ssh2 PECL library, then you can use its functions to do what you want.  Depending on what OS you are running on the server, you may need to run `pecl install ssh2` or possibly even just install `php-pecl-ssh2` (or similar) from your package manager.

Comment: check rsync it may be helpfull for you